# Sharing an image and url with WhatsApp HTML link

Tags: javascript, html, whatsapp

I would like to have a link on a web page that allows the user to send an image (with preview) and a separate link to a webpage.

It would be something like this:

```html
<a href="https://wa.me/?text=https://images.com/image1.jpg%20https://mycoolwebsite.com">Share on WhatsApp!</a>
```

However this just returns 2 links. I'm aware I could just have `og` meta tags on my html page, but I would like a larger image displaying.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance :)